# Firebase Chat App - Stop typing indicator after timeout

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing chat functionality in an iOS app I'm making, using Firebase's Realtime DB. I've implemented a 'typing indicator' where if the user starts typing, a flag is flipped to true in the DB.

What would be the best/ safest way to set this back to false after a certain amount of time of no activity from the user, ~5 seconds? This could be easy on the client by just reseting a timeout every time the user starts typing. However, what if the client crashes/ users quits before this timeout.

Would it be better to use Firebase's Cloud Functions to run a function every time the indicator is set to true by watching the key and then doing the timeout on the server? This sounds safer but quite costly when things start to scale.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I would suggest looking at [-onDisconnectSetValue:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseReference#/c:objc(cs)FIRDatabaseReference(im)onDisconnectSetValue:) which, if the clients disconnects, a node value can be set to false. Firebase has no timers and if there is a disconnect of both clients (per the accepted answer) then you're whole system will get out of sync.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting the logic on the server is a good approach for the reasons you specified.

Another alternative would be to replace the indicator flag with a "senderLastTypedSomething" timestamp. That way the receiving client could just check the timestamp and display its indicator appropriately. Kind of a "dead man's switch" in case the sending client disappears.

Comment: Nice idea, I'll implement it and see how it works out! Thanks

Comment: Worked out nicely. Updating the timestamp on the DB every couple of seconds if the user is still typing. Then each time the timestamp is updated, this fires a function on the other client to store the timestamp and check whether it's still the same in 5 seconds time